# How to find a control in ASP.NET LoginView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I can't find my label ID in LoginView Control, Just to explain what i'm trying to build. If you are NOT logged in you can only see the content from the database, but if your ARE logged in you can edit it. But right now i just need help to make it read the data from the database

Here is the ASP.NET Code-Behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=10.138.22.47;Initial Catalog=Student10157;User ID=Studentxxxxx;Password=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"))
        {
            connection.Open();

            SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("Select * from Content_Text", connection);
            SqlDataReader dr;
            dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.Read())
            {

                lblLeft.text = dr["Text"].ToString();
            } 
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here is my ASP.NET code:

```
<asp:FormView runat="server" ID="viewdata">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
            <AnonymousTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblLeft" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </AnonymousTemplate>
            <LoggedInTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TxBLeft" runat="server" />
            </LoggedInTemplate>
        </asp:LoginView>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

I have tried as you can see to use a formview with the following C# code but that dont work either `var lblLeft = (Label)viewData.FindControl("lblLeft");`

Comment: Please give more details about "that don't work". Do you get compile errors (if yes, which one) ? Do you get an exception at runtime ?

Comment: If you plan to read at most 1 row from the db, use the ExecuteScalar method.

Comment: why you use FormView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FormView` need in datasource, so i think you need somethink like this in your code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=10.138.22.47;Initial Catalog=Student10157;User ID=Studentxxxxx;Password=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"))
        {
            connection.Open();

            SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("Select * from Content_Text", connection);
            SqlDataReader dr;
            dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                viewdata.DataSource = new []{new { N = dr["Text"] }};
                viewdata.DataBind();

            } 
        }
    }
}
```

and markup

```
<asp:FormView runat="server" ID="viewdata">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LoginView runat="server">
            <AnonymousTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblLeft" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("N") %>'></asp:Label>
            </AnonymousTemplate>
            <LoggedInTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TxBLeft" runat="server" />
            </LoggedInTemplate>
        </asp:LoginView>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

**UPDATE**
if you have a few `content_text` you can try something like this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=10.138.22.47;Initial Catalog=Student10157;User ID=Studentxxxxx;Password=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"))
        {
            connection.Open();

            SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("Select * from Content_Text", connection);
            SqlDataReader dr;
            dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
            List<object> ds = new List<object>();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                ds.Add(new { N = dr["Text"] });
            } 

            viewdata.DataSource = ds;
            viewdata.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This.

```
if (dr.Read())
{
    Label lblLeft = (Label)viewData.FindControl("lblLeft")
    lblLeft.text = dr["Text"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: It found the Label so thanks, but i still get an error when i run the site.


 Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.


Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the label in it's `NamingContainer` which is the `ItemTemplate` of the `FormView`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (viewdata.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.ReadOnly)
    {
        LoginView lv = (LoginView)viewdata.FindControl("LoginView1");
        Label lblLeft = (Label)lv.FindControl("lblLeft");
    }
}
```

By the way, you should databind the label only if its not a postback:

```
if(!IsPostBack && viewdata.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.ReadOnly)
{
    LoginView lv = (LoginView)viewdata.FindControl("LoginView1");
    Label lblLeft = (Label)lv.FindControl("lblLeft");
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=10.138.22.47;Initial Catalog=Student10157;User ID=Studentxxxxx;Password=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using(var cm = new SqlCommand("Select TOP 1 Text from Content_Text", connection))
        using(SqlDataReader dr = cm.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if(dr.Read())
            {
                lblLeft.Text = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("Text"));
            }   
        }    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find label in LoginView control as following:

```
LoginView logView = (LoginView)viewdata.FindControl("LoginView1");
Label lblLeft = (Label)logView.FindControl("lblLeft");
lblLeft.Text = "Your text goes here";
```